# No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time' - Exchangelib Module - Python

Tags: python3

I have the following issue. I'm working with Python 32-bit on win32. I've installed Exchangelib 1.12.5, however when trying to import the module, I get the following error:

> ```
> File "C:\Users\adu-amponan\AppData\Local\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\x509\extensions.py", line 19, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.primitives import constant_time, serialization
> File "C:\Users\adu-amponan\AppData\Local\Python\lib\site-packages\cryptography\hazmat\primitives\constant_time.py", line 11, in <module>
>     from cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time import lib
> ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cryptography.hazmat.bindings._constant_time'
> ```

If I navigate to the "cryptography/hazmat/bindings" directory, I can locate the _constant_time file however I notice that the file has a ".cp37-win_amd64" file extension.

As I am working with Python 32-bit on win32, could this be the reason for this error or is there another issue? If the issue related to a mismatch in versions where can I download the win32 version of exchangelib?